# Rotate sine wave on complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers

Quick one. How do you rotate a sine wave on the complex plane? I already rotated the point $0+i$ to get the unit circle and graphed $n,e^{i \pi n}$ to get a sine wave, which is what all the examples are about. I now want to rotate the result at a $45^\circ$ angle. How do you do that?

Comment: How do you graph $n,e^{i \pi n}$ and in what sense is the graph "a sine wave"?

Comment: If you treat those two terms as coordinates of the cartesian plane you get a sine wave. You’re literally stretching the circle out.

Comment: For $n$ not an integer, $e^{i\pi n}$ is a complex number. How do you use it as a coordinate of the Cartesian plane? Perhaps you are thinking of $(x, \Re(e^{i\pi x}))$, but that is not what you wrote.

Comment: That’s correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rotate the complex plane 45 degrees counterclockwise (and any graph within it at the same time) by multiplying each point by $\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$.

You should be aware that, depending on your rotation, it may not be a graph of the real component of the complex number anymore, though.

Comment: Yeah, I used the input as the real part of the complex number to get a wave from the circle and just multiplied that number by $1+i$. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, but the you should be aware that your graph has been scaled as well as rotated.

Comment: oh I see that now. Is that what the $\sqrt{2}$ is for, to correct that?

Comment: @dataphile Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Ok, cool, thanks